# Registering a shape in python's turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

**My problem:**

I am attempting to register a shape with the python turtle module, however it is refusing to work. The gif in question is [this](https://giphy.com/gifs/1oHoIcBOzddzmiaAZQ) and it is located in my downloads folder with the title tenor.gif. I am running this code in the IDE, Canopy, in Python 3.

If I restart the kernel and then run the code, I consistently get the **same output**, verifying I have the right directory:

```
%run "C:/Users/AlexPC/Python Programs/Chess.py"
C:\Users\AlexPC\Downloads
C:\Users\AlexPC\Downloads
```

and the **same error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\AlexPC\Python Programs\Chess.py in <module>()
     37 print(os.getcwd())
     38 s.register_shape("tenor.gif")
---> 39 t.shape("tenor.gif")
     40 
     41 
C:\Users\AlexPC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\turtle.py in shape(self, name)
   2775         if not name in self.screen.getshapes():
   2776             raise TurtleGraphicsError("There is no shape named %s" % name)
-> 2777         self.turtle._setshape(name)
   2778         self._update()
   2779 
C:\Users\AlexPC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\turtle.py in _setshape(self, shapeIndex)
   2504             self._item = screen._createpoly()
   2505         elif self._type == "image":
-> 2506             self._item = screen._createimage(screen._shapes["blank"]._data)
   2507         elif self._type == "compound":
   2508             self._item = [screen._createpoly() for item in
C:\Users\AlexPC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\turtle.py in _createimage(self, image)
    721         """Create and return image item on canvas.
    722         """
--> 723         return self.cv.create_image(0, 0, image=image)
    724 
    725     def _drawimage(self, item, pos, image):
<string> in create_image(self, *args, **kw)
C:\Users\AlexPC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in create_image(self, *args, **kw)
   2327     def create_image(self, *args, **kw):
   2328         """Create image item with coordinates x1,y1."""
-> 2329         return self._create('image', args, kw)
   2330     def create_line(self, *args, **kw):
   2331         """Create line with coordinates x1,y1,...,xn,yn."""
C:\Users\AlexPC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in _create(self, itemType, args, kw)
   2318         return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
   2319             self._w, 'create', itemType,
-> 2320             *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
   2321     def create_arc(self, *args, **kw):
   2322         """Create arc shaped region with coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2."""
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

**My code:**

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import os


t = Turtle("square")
t.shapesize(4,4)
t.hideturtle()
t.pu()  
t.goto(-280,-280)

s = Screen()
s.clearscreen()
s.tracer(False)
s.screensize(800,800)

#register the piece shapes
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\AlexPC\\Downloads")
print(os.getcwd())
s.register_shape("tenor.gif")
t.shape("tenor.gif")
```

Comment: Instead of `s = Screen()`, try `s = t.getscreen()`.  I believe you are registering your shape in a different instance of `Screen` than what your turtle is using, thus the inability to find it.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gives the same error.

Comment: @jasonharper, there is no "different instance of `Screen`" in *standalone* turtle -- the screen instance is singular and you get the same one from `Screen()` as from `Turtle.getscreen()`.  (If you use turtle *embeded* in your own tkinter code, you can have separate screen instances running around, but that's not the case here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues.  First, your image link led to an animated GIF -- there's nothing in the turtle documentation about animated GIF support.  You'll likely just get a static GIF image at best, nothing at worst.

Second, your example code has unrelated and unecessary stuff.  Let's simplify and focus on the problem:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import os

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(800, 800)
os.chdir(""C:\\Users\\AlexPC\\Downloads"")
screen.register_shape("tenor.gif")

turtle = Turtle("tenor.gif")
turtle.penup()  
turtle.goto(-280, -280)

screen.mainloop()
```

This worked for me on a Unix system, putting the image in a "Downloads" directory under my current directory and using a relative `os.chdir()` to relocate there -- I don't know if this is a Windows-specific problem.  Give the above a try to see if it works any better for you.

Comment: It seems as though the issue wasn't within the code, but rather the issue laid with my usage of the IDE, Canopy, as I tried the same code in the Python IDLE shell, and it worked just fine.

Comment: What's more, the issue was specific to something in canopy, the solution I found in [this](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469880-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-or-Pyglet-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel), and told you to switch the 'backend' that canopy uses with PyLab to one called "Inline (SVG)".

Comment: @aargon, nice detective work.  I'm glad you're moving forward again.

Answer (score 0):

First
`turtle.addshape("tenor.gif")`, then `pen.shape("tenor.gif")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.